# storing a List using Django REST framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a model that contains the newly added `ListField` class in DRF.
I am trying to store a List of strings so the output would look like so:

```
{

    "hashtags":["something", "new"],

}
```

I'm pretty new to working with DRF but I seem to be having some trouble serializing the result. When I run the request I received a 
`HashField() is not JSON serializable`  error.  Again I'm new to working with the the framework and Python in general but any suggestions, point in the right direction would be a help.

**models.py**

```
class HashField(serializers.ListField):
    child = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)

 class Mention(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    hashtags = HashField()      
    placename = models.CharField(max_length=140, default='SOME STRING')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
            default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(
            blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.placename
```

**serializers.py**

```
class MentionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Mention
```

Comment: I provided an update with an answer over here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34194246/posting-a-list-using-django-rest-frameworks/34211237#34211237

Answer (score 1):

Django REST Framework has different kind of serializers, what you need here is a field serializer that validates a list type.
in **serializers.py** do as follow:

```
class MentionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    hashtags = serializers.ListField()
    class Meta:
        model = Mention
```

Comment: thank @dhiatn. I tried that, now getting exception  "Got a `TypeError` when calling `Mention.objects.create()`. This may be because you have a writable field on the serializer class that is not a valid argument to `Mention.objects.create()`. You may need to make the field read-only, or override the MentionSerializer.create() method to handle this correctly.
Original exception text was: 'hashtags' is an invalid keyword argument for this function."

Comment: @gregdevs I will recommend to use [ArrayField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#querying-arrayfield) in th model field:
 `hashtags = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=100), blank=True)`
and the serializers.ListField in the DRF serializer
 `hashtags = serializers.ListField()`.

Comment: that's right and it will be great if you switch to PostgreSQL, because in the next django realease 1.9 there will be more support for complex data-structure and PostgreSQL will offer you more flexiblity and efficiency.
__You still can you use this third party module__ [jsonfield](https://github.com/bradjasper/django-jsonfield) it works fine with MySQL too @gregdevs.

Comment: thanks, going to check this out in a  bit, will let you know on my progress. thanks again for the help

Comment: great and best of luck

Comment: finally figured this out.  Had to sort through the DRF documentation but, got the List functionality working.