# posting a List using Django Rest Frameworks

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

New to using DRF.  Curious as to what approaches some of you have used regarding storing a List.... I tried to implement the newly added [ListField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#listfield) but I was not able to get it working.  I'm using MySql as the db. I figured there was a DRF-specific way of achieving this.

For example, say this is the expected output:

```
{
    "somenames": ["james", "jim"],
    "somekey": "username",
}
```

models.py

```
class StringListField(serializers.ListField):
    child = serializers.CharField()

class SomeClass(models.Model):
    somenames = StringListField,
    somekey =  models.CharField(max_length=140, default='username')


    def publish(self):
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.somekey
```

serializers.py

```
class MentionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Mention
        fields = ('somekey', 'somenames')
```

One option I could implement is just storing the List as a seperate table then reflecting them in the table I need them to nest them in with `Foreign Key` or `ManyToManyField`. Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: This is one such reason I refrain from using Djangorest.

Comment: @itsneo Since I just started getting into Django not too long ago,  kind of assumed to stick with one base and check out their Rest frame work as well...have you used any python supported frameworks like flash restful for building an api?  I'll keep digging around for a solution here.

Comment: If you are thinking about flask no one cat beat Eve's framework. http://python-eve.org/rest_api_for_humans.html by a cool guy from Italy

Comment: @itsneo cool. Will check it out. Seems like it has some built in support for bulk crud. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I use this

```
deep_link = serializers.ListSerializer(child=serializers.CharField())
```

it's basically a shortcut of yours. The problem with your code is that you are confusing Models with Serializers. The Model is the database representation of your data. The model does not specify serializers. The serializer is the serialized representation of your model coming from the DB, used mostly for data transfer.

```
class SomeClass(models.Model):
    somenames = StringListField
    somekey =  models.CharField(max_length=140, default='username')
```

here, you are telling your model that your Django model's field "somenames" is of type serializers.ListSerializers. That is not what you want. If you want to link a model to a list of strings you need to create a ManyToMany relationship or whatever you need. Below an example

```
class Name(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class SomeClass(models.Model):
    somekey = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    somenames = models.ManyToManyField(Names)
```

Then in your serializers you will have

```
class NameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()

class SomeClassSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    somenames = NameSerializer(many=True)
    somekey = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = SomeClass
```

Comment: So i tried adding this to my model and I get this error ```ListField(child=CharField()) is not JSON serializable```

Comment: ListSerializer, not ListField

Comment: Ahh, missed that.  and yes I corrected that, same error ```ListSerializer(child=CharField(default='Username', max_length=140)) is not JSON serializable```

Comment: Ok, i think the issue is another. I am updating the answer.

Comment: Thank you for checking it out, I haven't had much luck finding any posts with this same problem. I thought it might be the version of DRF, but im fully up to date.

Comment: I hope I clarified your issues

Comment: This makes much more sense. So Basically I need to create a class (in your example, Names)   for each item in a list,which would then be used as a many to many relationship in the parent model.  Thanks a lot, will let you know on my progress

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after delving into the DRF documentation, along with the help of [@xbirkettx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4391054/xbirkettx) answer, I was able to achieve the result I wanted:

in models.py
Create your models. I set a `ForeignKey` relationship to the parent class (in this case the `Mention` class)

```
class Mention(models.Model):
     ...


class Hashtag(models.Model):
    mention = models.ForeignKey(Mention, related_name='hashtags')
    tagname = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('mention', 'tagname')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.tagname)
```

in serializers.py
Create the serializers for the item in the List (Hashtag)
for read/write you need to define `to_internal_value` method

```
class HashListingField(serializers.RelatedField):  
    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        tagname = data
        return {
            'tagname': tagname
        }
    def to_representation(self, value):
        return value.tagname
```

be sure to add the `queryset` argument to the serializer for write access

```
class MentionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    hashtags = HashListingFieldSerializer(many=True, queryset=Hashtag.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = Mention


    def create(self, validated_data):
        tags_data = validated_data.pop('hashtags')
        mention = Mention.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for tags_data in tags_data:
            Hashtag.objects.create(mention=mention, **tags_data)
        return mention
```